# Why is this script only work on double click rather than single click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, fadein, onclicklistener

Code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.click1').click(function () {
    $(".show1").fadeIn(400);
});

$('body, .click1').click(function() { 
    $('.show1').hide(); 
});
});
</script>
```

The script above works but in order for it to do the fadeIn it needs to be clicked twice.  How can I change it so that it shows when clicked once?

Comment: try $('.click1').click(function () {
    $(".show1").hide().fadeIn(400);
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case, you can apply the event listener to the body of the document (in this case, you're listening for when a click happens anywhere on the page). Once that event occurs, you can see what was clicked specifically (evt.target) and from there conditionally fire functions.

http://codepen.io/snypelife/pen/Fcjiw

```
$(function () {

      $('body').on('click', function (evt) {
        if($(evt.target).hasClass('click')){
          $('.show').toggle('fade');
        } else {
          $('.show').fadeOut();
        }
      });

});
```

Comment: the one you posted doesn't hide it when clicked anywhere else.

Comment: I updated the pen I made.  I wasn't sure what the goal was initally but I think I understand what you were after now.

Comment: Thanks but it should also close if click here is closed again.  if you can add that then that would complete it.  thanks!

Comment: So what you could do is apply the event listener to the body and then check what the target was that was clicked and decide on the action from there.

Comment: lol sorry, I'm thinking faster than I'm typing.  Basically for your use case, you can apply the event listener to the body of the document (in this case, you're listening for when a click happens anywhere on the page).  Once that event occurs, you can see what was clicked specifically (evt.target) and from there conditionally fire functions.

Answer (score 0):

The click event (as the most of the other events) bubbles to the parent elements. It effectively means that when you click on the '.click1' element this event first triggered on this element and then it is triggered on 'body'. And the event listener on 'body' instantly hides the element.
You can use Event.stopPropagation() here to prevent event bubbling:

```
$('.click1').click(function (e) {
    $(".show1").fadeIn(400);
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('body').click(function() { 
    $('.show1').hide(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried using that but got this error: ReferenceError: e is not defined
error source line:
 

e.stopPropagation();

Comment: @starbucks Make sure you are passing `e` as the first parameter of your click handler function.